# Transform column values into columns with counts in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, where I would like to separate column values into columns and sum the categories, grouping by 2 columns.

**Data**

```
tar date    ex  ppr stat
aa  q122    bb  10  hi
aa  q122    bb  15  hello
aa  q122    bb  10  hi
cc  q222    zz  20  hey
cc  q222    zz  15  hello
```

**Desired**

```
tar date    count   ppr_sum hi  hello   hey
aa  q122    3       35      2   1       0
cc  q222    2       35      0   1       1
```

**Doing**

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(index = [df['tar'], df['date']], columns = df['stat'])
ppr_sum = df1.groupby(['tar','date'])['ppr'].sum()
```

Still not obtaining the sum of the stat column. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `get_dummies` and `groupby`:

```
 >>> pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='', prefix='', columns=['stat']).groupby(['tar', 'date'], as_index=False).sum().assign(count=df.groupby(['tar', 'date'], as_index=False)['ex'].size()['size'])
  tar  date  ppr  hello  hey  hi  count
0  aa  q122   35      1    0   2      3
1  cc  q222   35      1    1   0      2
>>>
```